# Insert powerpoint slide into running presentation

Tags: insert, real-time, powerpoint, slideshow

The main idea: a user creates a powerpoint file with 1 slide, and this slide is inserted into a slideshow which is already looping.
A first idea I had was to convert the .ppt file into an image (e.g. using http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter/ or a .NET API), and then create a flash application which scans a directory for images(/converted slides) to show.

But this seems a bit like a complex solution, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the insert object feature in PowerPoint.

1. Choose Insert from file
2. Select the powerpoint file
3. Check Link Checkbox

And its done. Any changes in the linked file are reflected in the already looping show. Let me know if you don't get it.